# what are steps required to write our custom parser plugin for nutch1.17 and any example

Tags: nutch

can Anyone explain with an example to write custom parser plugin to write in nutch and steps required to write custom plugin.**strong text**

Answer (score 3):

Although, it is supposed that you should ask some question related to programming here. If you are well in Java, you should be able to understand the code structure of Nutch. Just as a hack, you can follow these steps

1. Copy some existing parser plugin e.g., parse-html
2. Change the class name and other details in .java and .xml files
3. Develop or customize the plugin according to you need
4. Add plugin in nutch-site.xml
5. Use "parsechecker" tool in Nutch for testing